# Append/Join Composed Objects of psycopg2.sql.SQL

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have two variables `a` and `b` which contain whether `Composed([])` ([Class](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/sql.py#L86)) or are filled with something like e.g.`Composed([Composed([Composed([SQL('trunc('), Identifier('s0'), SQL(' * '), Literal(Decimal('1.000000')), SQL(', '), Literal(2), SQL(') AS '), Identifier('Test XXXX')])])])`.

How can I join or extend them with a separator (only if needed) in between and assign them to a variable named `c`.

My unsuccessful try so far:

```
c = sql.SQL(', ').join(filter(sql.Composed, [a, b]))
```

Feels I am missing something trivial.

***Edit***:

This works but still could be better:

```
sql.SQL(', ').join(
    q for q in [a, b] if q.seq
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql.SQL(', ').join(
    q for q in [a, b] if q.seq
)
```

Be aware if you use this code snippet since `Composed` only has this property set if it holds a list.

Answer (score -1):

`c = sql.SQL(', ').join([a, b])` will do

Comment: This results in `Composed([Composed([]), SQL(', '), ...` which is invalid SQL syntax when I pass it to the `execute` method.

Comment: what about use of the `+` operator? would `a + sql.SQL(', ') + b` work?

Comment: @FreyGeospatial I think not, but it's a good idea. Might add it to psycopg 3.1...

no, I'm wrong: `+` is supported already.
`sql.Identifier("foo") + sql.SQL(", ") + sql.Identifier("bar")`
`Composed([Identifier('foo'), SQL(', '), Identifier('bar')])`